# Is there a way to wipe an entire Neo4j database via the REST API?

Tags: rest, neo4j, neography

I'm using the [Neography](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography) gem to interact with a Neo4j database through the REST API. I don't see any way in Neography itself (though if it's there, I'd love to use it!), nor have I been able to find by searching on Google whether this is possible directly through the REST API itself. Does anyone out there with Neo4j experience happen to know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Neography, you can send this Gremlin script:

```
@neo = Neography::Rest.new
@neo.execute_script("g.clear()")
```

to remove all the nodes and relationships.

Answer (score 0):

To clear all nodes and relationships except the root node, use the solution provided in [neography wiki](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography/wiki/Testing)

```
@neo = Neography::Rest.new
@neo.execute_query("START n0=node(0),nx=node(*) MATCH n0-[r0?]-(),nx-[rx?]-() WHERE nx <> n0 DELETE r0,rx,nx")
```